# Cannot extend jboss-eap-7 container

Tags: docker, jboss, containers, redhat

i using this container: `registry.redhat.io/jboss-eap-7/eap74-openjdk17-openshift-rhel8`

when is start the container without extending the container works fine:

```
$> docker run registry.redhat.io/jboss-eap-7/eap74-openjdk17-openshift-rhel8
```

but when i try to extend the image with a `Dockerfile` (as described on the [redhat page](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html-single/using_the_red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform_docker_image/index#extending-the-image)) the container does not start up, with an error message that i cannot understand nor know how to solve it:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM registry.redhat.io/jboss-eap-7/eap74-openjdk17-openshift-rhel8

CMD ["/opt/eap/bin/standalone.sh", "-b", "0.0.0.0", "-bmanagement", "0.0.0.0"]
```

then build an run

```
$>docker image build -t test:latest .
$>docker run test:latest
```

i get the following error:

```
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /opt/eap

  JAVA: /usr/lib/jvm/java-17/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS: -javaagent:"/opt/eap/jboss-modules.jar"  -server -Xlog:gc*:file="/opt/eap/standalone/log/gc.log":time,uptimemillis:filecount=5,filesize=3M -Djdk.serialFilter="maxbytes=10485760;maxdepth=128;maxarray=100000;maxrefs=300000" -Xms1303m -Xmx1303m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=jdk.nashorn.api,com.sun.crypto.provider -Djava.awt.headless=true -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=20 -XX:GCTimeRatio=4 -XX:AdaptiveSizePolicyWeight=90 -XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom  -Djboss.modules.settings.xml.url=file:///opt/jboss/container/wildfly/s2i/galleon/settings.xml  --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.url.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.url.ldaps=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/javax.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming=ALL-UNNAMED

=========================================================================

Formatter ##CONSOLE-FORMATTER## is not defined
```

Comment: You are not using the proper script: /opt/eap/bin/openshift-launch.sh which set-up the configuration. I guess you need to check what is done there